# What are good forums or mailing lists for programmers new to Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

I would like to start a Community Wiki on good resources for programmers new to Smalltalk. I'm especially looking for good forums and/or mailing lists for programmers that are new to Smalltalk. Please correct me if I'm wrong (this is a wiki after all), but what I've found so far seem to be geared toward current Smalltalk programmers than to "newbies":

[seaside](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/seaside)
[GNU-smalltalk](http://www.mail-archive.com/help-smalltalk@gnu.org/info.html)
[Object-Mix](http://objectmix.com/smalltalk/)

Alternately, is Stack Overflow a good source? I noticed that there are only 100 questions tagged "Smalltalk" on Stack Overflow, but over 3000 for Perl.

Comment: The name of the language is "Smalltalk" - no uppercase "T".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a beginners mailing list.

- [beginner mailing list info](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/beginners)
- [beginner mailing list archive](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/beginners/)

I am not a member of that list myself, but it seems to be alive and well run.

Asking on SO is also welcome, of course :)

Comment: Yes, beginners list of Squeak is full active and responsive.

Answer (score 2):

Most activity is on the [squeak-dev](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/squeak-dev) and [pharo](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/pharo-project/) mailing lists. They are developer lists for the squeak and pharo dialects, but are pretty open to newbies. Please don't hesitate to ask questions there. The seaside-dev list on the other hand is developer only. For Pier (the Seaside CMS) and Magrite (meta-description framework) look [here](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/pipermail/smallwiki/). Squeak foundation also hosts a lot of more [specific lists](http://lists.squeakfoundation.org/pipermail/).
If you're into software reengineering, take a look [here](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/pipermail/moose-dev/)

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is the usenet group:

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.smalltalk

There are actually a few more usenet groups, but this is the only remotely active one.

Comment: hmm, the dolphin group has daily activity

Answer (score 1):

Also there are specific groups for different Smalltalk implementations:

[vwnc -- Discussion of VisualWorks Noncommercial](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/vwnc)

[comp.lang.smalltalk.dolphin](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.smalltalk.dolphin/topics?pli=1)

[VA Smalltalk 7.0, 7.5 & 8.0](http://www.instantiations.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=12)